# How to adjust image size using TCPDF

Tags: laravel-5, tcpdf

I started use TCPDF. I scuess to display image file but I couldn't adjust size. 
jpg file is stored at laravel's [public] folder.Could someone teach me what is wrong my code please?

Controller

```
$pdf = new TCPDF("P", "mm", "A4", true, "UTF-8" );
$pdf->setPrintHeader(false);
$pdf->setPrintFooter(false);

$pdf->setFont('kozminproregular','',10);        
$pdf->addPage();      
$pdf->writeHTML(view("pdf2", $data)->render());        
$pdf->output('test' . '.pdf', 'D');
return;
```

blade file

```
<img src="photo.jpg" alt="logo" width="300px" height="300px">
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try close img tag. Delete "px".

```
<img src="photo.jpg" alt="logo" width="300" height="300" />
```